# how to configure mahout with play framework

Tags: eclipse, playframework, mahout, playframework-2.2, mahout-recommender

How can I include mahout 0.9 libraries in play-framework 2.2.
I have added the jar files in the build path of eclipse but when I run the play app the following error is displayed for mahout imports

```
error: package org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this line in build.sbt of play project

```
"org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-core" % "0.9"
```

Full build.sbt looks like this

```
name := <your_project_name>

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.apache.mahout" % "mahout-core" % "0.9"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```